# Received byte array has different values than sent, AES encryption + IV

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, aes

I'm trying to encrypt communication using AES, in java.

The key is hardcoded, and the IV is generated randomly through a SecureRandom and sent as the first 16 bytes of the encrypted message. However, when I try to read the first 16 bytes of the received message, I don't get the same byte array that I generated.

Here's the problematic code:

```
static byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

public static byte[] encrypt(String key, String message) {
    try {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(bytes);

        System.out.println("Outputting generated IV:");
        for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++){
            System.out.println(bytes[i]);
        }

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(bytes);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("encrypted string: "
                + Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted));

        byte[] sendMe = new byte[bytes.length + encrypted.length];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, sendMe, 0, bytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, sendMe, 0, encrypted.length);

        return  sendMe;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String key, byte[] received) {
    try {

        byte[] initVector = Arrays.copyOfRange(received, 0, 16);
        byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(received, 16, received.length+1);

        System.out.println("Outputting received IV:");
        for(int i = 0; i < initVector.length; i++){
            System.out.println(initVector[i]);
        }

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Running this once, for example's sake, with the text "Hello world!" yielded the following output:

```
Outputting generated IV:
-79
-3
102
-103
-13
67
-63
-18
23
-114
74
26
18
-97
77
115
Outputting received IV:
36
-118
-87
-72
-119
43
101
55
50
-62
125
-98
65
35
48
-87
```

Which are obviously not the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your **IV** with the **encrypted data**:

```
 System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, sendMe, 0, bytes.length);
 System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, sendMe, 0, encrypted.length);  // Overwrites the iv
```

You probably want:

```
 System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, sendMe, 0, bytes.length);
 System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, sendMe, 16, encrypted.length);
```

Comment: You know when you've been looking at the same code for so long you can't see stupid errors like this anymore? I'm sorry for wasting your time with retarded errors like these, but thanks a lot for the help!